# Paypal integration, how to use createOrder onApprove?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

The paypal documentation here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/

States that

> Within createOrder and onApprove, call your server-side using the Fetch API to retrieve a token or capture a payment. Within createOrder, return the Order ID (or EC token) generated from your server-side code.

Are there are any examples of how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server